# How Do I create a Mining Pool for an Altcoin?

Tags: mining-pools, altcoin, solo-mining, altcoin-development

I made an altcoin using coincreator.net , but I can only mine it on an underpowered windows computer. I was wanting to make a pool so that my friends and I could mine it together from a Windows or a Mac computer. If no one knows how to do this, then could anyone tell me how to solo mine on a computer that does not have the altcoin wallet? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to clarify details. Ie is it POW or POS? SHA256 or Scrypt or something else? Re `I can only mine it on an underpowered windows computer`, I'm not following you here. Why do you need to mine your own coin faster? Just so you know, the reason you don't find this information online is because there is no *copy/paste* method of starting an altcoin, it's extremely complicated even if you can code C++.

Answer (score 3):

Check out MPOS, here is a guide to setting up an MPOS pool:

https://github.com/MPOS/php-mpos/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide

And, to answer your last question, it is impossible to solo mine standard coins on a single computer that does not have the alt coin wallet in question installed.

Comment: and if the target altcoin wallet doesn’t provide a mining port ? and the altcoin wallet doesn’t release it’s source code ? Is there a way to go ahead straight from databases ? I’m thinking about https://gmdcoin.co.